# How to normalize a recursive relationship? (Conceptual to logical)

Tags: schema, rdbms, erd, conceptual-model

[conceptual ERD of a recursive relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxSAW.png)

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. PS Definitions are recursive. Not relationships aka associations or "relationships" aka FKs. Nothing here is defined in terms of itself.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please show your steps working through what your textbook says & ask a specific question where you are first stuck & explain about why. Quote definitions & algorithms. The reason you can't answer this question is that you are not already doing that. Now you are just asking us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your homework.

Answer (score -1):

This relationship is employee mentor employees and employees mentored by employee.
since this is an Optional both side and one to many relationship, you just need to create a foreign key mentor(Fk) inside the employee table and remove the recursive line form the table.

Comment: Thank-you so much XD